# InputMethodManager keyword is not defined in android app

Tags: android, keyword, inputmethodmanager

I am trying to use the following code to hide the soft keyboard when a user clicks a button:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

But I get an error:

> InputMethodManager not defined

I am thinking I need to add an import statement? If so does anyone know what?
Or how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`InputMethodManager` is in package `android.view.inputmethod`, so you need to add

```
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
```

to your class.

Comment: In the future, if you are using eclipse, press (on a mac) Command + Shift + o to resolve all imports (and Control + Shift + o on windows)

Comment: even Better help... THANKS so much!